# how to Create array in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, array

Can you Please help me how to Create `array` in LWC

```
  @track arraydata = [];
 let rtValues = Object.values(this.studentsData);
  for (let i = 0; i < rtValues.length; i++) {
  this.arrayStudentprogram = rtValues[i].studentprogram;
    this.arraydata.push(this.arrayStudentprogram);
    this.arrayStudentInfo = rtValues[i].studentOtherInfo;
    this.arraydata.push(this.arrayStudentInfo);
    alert(this.arrayStudentprogram);
    alert(this.arrayStudentInfo);
    alert(this.arraydata);
  }
 alert(this.arraydata);
  return;
```

`alert(this.arraydata);` returns empty value. Can you help me what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.arraydata.push(this.arrayStudentprogram);` not `this.arraydata.push[this.arrayStudentprogram];`